# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Grid hgap=10.0

Tags: javafx, barcode-scanner, scene

my name is Omar, I made this code  in javafx in order to switch between scene 0 and scene 1.
When an input scanner laser barcode number is introduced (6590055780)
it changes from scene 0 to scene 1, once in scene 1, if user pressed a button will change to scene 0.
But when i compile this code, it gives me the following error

"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Grid hgap=10.0 alignment=CENTERis already set as root of another scene"

I do not know why i get this error, it is like the setOnKeyPressed does not allow me to leave from it,  when i want to switch from scene 0 to scene 1, i got this error message, anyhelp is appreciated in order to solve this problem. thank you very much

and this is the code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class scannerinputfx2 extends Application {
////////////* public class*///////

public static  String salida;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
primaryStage.setTitle("what's up");



//scene 0
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(10);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
TextArea area = new TextArea();
TextField userTextField = new TextField();
//grid.add(userTextField, 0, 0);
//grid.add(area, 0,1);
GridPane.setConstraints(userTextField, 0,0);
GridPane.setConstraints(area,0,1);
grid.getChildren().addAll(area, userTextField);

//scene 1
GridPane grid1 = new GridPane();
grid1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
grid1.setHgap(10);
grid1.setVgap(10);
grid1.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
Scene scene1 = new Scene(grid1, 300, 275);
Button btnfinal = new Button("Press button to get back");
GridPane.setConstraints(btnfinal, 0, 0);
grid1.getChildren().addAll(btnfinal);


btnfinal.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {   
scene1.setRoot(grid);
});

primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();


 userTextField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {


                 area.setText( userTextField.getText());


if (userTextField.getText().equals("6590055780"))
            {
      System.out.println("The number is " + userTextField.getText());

           userTextField.setText("");
           scene.setRoot(grid1);
             }
           else 
             {
      System.out.println("The number is not the indicated");
            }

            }


        });


}








////////*Here finish primary stage/////////
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



}
```

Comment: Why do you try to modify the scenes instead of replacing the scene in the `Stage`?

Comment: i am setting a  root scene with scene.setRoot(grid1);  in order to switch between scenes, but it seems like a need a kind of keylistener in order to get the input of a laser barcode